# Validating input, cannot contain string

Tags: java

im new here but been actively using the sites resources. Love it. Hope to make a positive contribution in the future.

On with my question, im trying to get a valid input that is only 1 or 2 or 3

```
    choice = stdin.nextInt();
            stdin.nextLine(); // Recalling scanner so it removes the empty string in       printUserName()
            while (!((choice == 1) || (choice == 2)|| (choice == 3))){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
                choice = stdin.nextInt();
        }
            while(!stdin.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
                choice = stdin.nextInt();
            }
            return choice;
   }
```

That is what i have but no luck for not allowing a input to be a string :/

Any help is greatly appreciated, this is extra work on java to help improve my skills

Comment: Check out `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Comment: Please post a compilable code.

Comment: Your logic seems totally broken: "while are no ints available, read ints."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to parse the `String` into an `int`, and then catch any exception that would mean it's not a number. Then just check if it is equal to 1, 2, or 3, like this:

```
boolean isInt = false;
choice = stdin.nextInt();
while (isInt == false){
int parsed = 0;
try{
   parsed = Integer.parseInt(choice);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
    choice = stdin.nextInt();
}
if (parsed != 0){
    isInt = true;   
}
if (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice && != 3){
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
    choice = stdin.nextInt();
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, im amending it a little but on point with what i was having trouble with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can go for below to check if input is numeric or not

[`NumberUtils.isNumber`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29) or [`StringUtils.isNumeric`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

You can have your own numeric function also

```
 public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
    {  
      try  
      {  
        int i = Integer.parseInt(str);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        return false;  
      }  
      return true;  
    }
```